# Passing variables between files in swift 2 not working with Struct method

Tags: swift, oop

Im using Xcode 7.2 and I wanted to pass a variable between .swift files. I tried using static variables inside structs as such: [in file 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WYRV.png) and then use this variable as such [in file 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFgTs.png). But Xcode doesn't recognize the struct. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to specify that SomeStruct is defined in File1.

So the new variable in File2 would be declared as:

```
var someOtherVar = File1.SomeStruct().someVariable
```